# jQuery Tabs Script - Question on adding something simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery tabs script found [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/).  What I am trying to do is add a class of "left" to one of them and a class of "right" to another one.  I am doing this because the border radius is different for the left and right side.

Since this script puts together my tabs, I can't just go in and add it how I want so I need a little help.  Specifications should have a left class, and Features should have a right class.

How can I add more information to the variable Tabs, and tell it which class to use?

**Part of my code is:**

```
var Tabs = {
    'Specifications'    : 'test.php?action=specifications',
    'Features'  : 'test.php?action=features',
}

/* Looping through the Tabs object: */
var z=0;
$.each(Tabs,function(i,j){
    /* Sequentially creating the tabs and assigning a color from the array: */
    var tmp = $('<li><a href="#" class="tab">'+i+'</a></li>');

    /* Setting the page data for each hyperlink: */
    tmp.find('a').data('page',j);

    /* Adding the tab to the UL container: */
    $('ul#tab').append(tmp);
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a quick [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), and explain on what criteria which one is given which class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add more data to your initial Tabs object:

```
var Tabs = {
    'Specifications':{class:"left",url:'test.php?action=specifications'},
    'Features':{class:"right",url:'test.php?action=features'}
}

/* Looping through the Tabs object: */
var z=0;
$.each(Tabs,function(i,j){
    /* Sequentially creating the tabs and assigning a color from the array: */
    var tmp = $('<li><a href="#" class="tab">'+i+'</a></li>')
        /* Setting the page data for each hyperlink: */
            .find('a')
            .addClass(j.class)
            .data('page',j.url)
            .end()
        /* Adding the tab to the UL container: */
        .appendTo($('ul#tab'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks! this actually makes it <ul id="tab" class="left right">

Comment: Thanks!  Now it puts it on the li.  instead of the li a.  Is it because the anchor already has a class of tab on it?

Comment: @Drew updated again. You might have said at the outset which tag you wanted the class added to....

Comment: Thank you it works perfect.  I apologize, I thought I mentioned it.  I should have been more clear.  Thanks again and sorry!

Comment: No problem -- as you can tell, I've had a long day. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use power of JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/b8Kpg/3/

```
var Tabs = [
    {'title':'Specifications', 'url': 'test.php?action=specifications', 'class': 'left'}
    {'title':'Features', 'url': 'test.php?action=features', 'class': 'right'}
]

$(Tabs).each(function(){
    /* Sequentially creating the tabs and assigning a color from the array: */
    var tmp = $('<li><a href="#" class="tab">'+this.title+'</a></li>');

    /* Setting the page data for each hyperlink: */
    tmp.find('a').data('page',this.url);

    tmp.addClass(this.class);

    /* Adding the tab to the UL container: */
    $('ul#tab').append(tmp);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! this adds it on the li instead of the a though.